# Dom - Input Not taken in JS

Tags: javascript

Guys I am learning javascript i just want to take the input from the text field and display it on the alert box but some how my input is always showing null. Here is my code

```js
var val = document.getElementById('val').value;

function testFunc() {
  alert(val);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return testFunc()">
  <input type="text" id="val" name="val">
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you do a submit of a form, it stops javascript execution as the control moves server side. If you want to make this work, change the type of your button to button, and add the click event handler to the button and call your testFunc() inside it.

Comment: `var val = document.getElementById('val').value;` does not extend into the future; if you want to grab the current `value` of your input, you have to do it *after* the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value inside the function , not outside, as when page loads the value is empty hence it shows the same value that was at page load for the input and not the current
see below

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return testFunc()">
  <input type="text" id="val" name="val">
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function testFunc() {
    var val = document.getElementById('val').value;
    alert(val);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `var val = document.getElementById('val').value;` inside of your handler function.

like

```js
function testFunc() {
    var val = document.getElementById('val').value;
    alert(val);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return testFunc()">
   <input type="text" id="val" name="val">
   <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Why: You only want to get value on page submit not when DOM loaded

Answer (score -1):

```
function testFunc(e){
e.preventDefault();

//add your code here
}
```

Just call your function. Don't return it